# django-private-storage configuration in nginx and Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am trying to use django-private-storage package to protect a model's file from being accessed
or downloaded by users who are not owners of the file.

I was able to do it successfully in development (using python manage.py runserver)

In development, I am using nginx configured via docker.

I can create objects with both FileField and PrivateFileField. My problem is accessing the urls associated with a PrivateFileField.

The mediafiles are being served as expected (e.g. when I access the url of a FileField), but I get a "404 Not Found" error from nginx when I access the url of a PrivateFileField.

My hunch is that the server response is not properly configured to have a 'X-Accel-Redirect' data,
thus treating the response not internal.

If I remove the line "internal;" in my nginx.conf for the private-data location, the PrivateFile is served
properly, although, now, it is not private.

```
    location /private-data/ {
        internal;  #<------ the PrivateFile can be accessed  if this line is removed
        alias /home/app/web/private-data/;
    }
```

Also, I am sure that the private file was saved in /home/app/web/private-data

Am I missing out something in the implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Additional info:

- nginx version: 1.17.4
- django-private-storage version: 2.2.2
- My production setup follows this:
  https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

**FILES** -----------------------------------

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn notify_django_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
      - private_volume:/home/app/web/private-data
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
      - private_volume:/home/app/web/private-data
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  private_volume:
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream django_project {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_project;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

    location /private-data/ {
        internal;
        alias /home/app/web/private-data/;
    }

}
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'private_storage',
    ....
]

PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "private-data")
PRIVATE_STORAGE_AUTH_FUNCTION = 'private_storage.permissions.allow_authenticated'
PRIVATE_STORAGE_INTERNAL_URL = '/private-data/'
PRIVATE_STORAGE_SERVER = 'nginx'
```

**models.py**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=get_attachment_save_path, null=True, blank=True)
    private_attachment = PrivateFileField(upload_subfolder=get_private_attachment_save_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('private-data/<str:code>/<int:year>/<str:subdir>/<uuid:pk>/<str:filename>', DownloadPrivateFileView.as_view(), name="file_download"),
    url('^private-data/', include(private_storage.urls)),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class DownloadPrivateFileView(PrivateStorageDetailView):
    model = Message
    model_file_field = 'private_attachment'

    def can_access_file(self, private_file):
        # When the object can be accessed, the file may be downloaded.
        # This overrides PRIVATE_STORAGE_AUTH_FUNCTION

        # grant_access checks private_file ownership
        grant_access = grant_note_access(private_file.request, message=self.get_object())
        return grant_access
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam in the testing phase with this library too!

I did not use these lines that indicated, which serves to speed up uploading large files.

without these settings and debug = False, everything worked correctly.

Take the test please.

Sorry for the Translation, I don't speak English

Comment: "I did not use these lines that indicated, which serves to speed up uploading large files."

What lines are you referring to?

Comment: location /private-data/ {
        internal;  #<------ the PrivateFile can be accessed  if this line is removed
        alias /home/app/web/private-data/;
    }. It may have something to do with the nginx settings. Then I post my settings so I can test.

My environment:
Nginx server on the computer running Docker.
A docker container on that computer with the Django App.

Answer (score 0):

My conf for my site in nginx **mysite.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com.br;
    return 301 https://mysite.com.br$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name mysite.com.br;

        location ~ ^/.well-known{
        root /var/www/myapp;
        }

        location / {
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6010;  # My container is at port 3020
        }

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Certificate free letsencrypt
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.br/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.br/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;


    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
}
```

My **setting.py** for django:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'anexosapp')  # Folder for files private app
MEDIA_URL = '/docs/'

# Conf for django-private-storage
INSTALLED_APPS += (
'private_storage',
)
PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'anexosapp/')
PRIVATE_STORAGE_AUTH_FUNCTION = 'private_storage.permissions.allow_authenticated'  # allow user authenticated

# settings for static server over whitenoise
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

**urls.py** app main:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('private-media/', include(private_storage.urls)),
]
```

The file access url looks like this
https : //mysite.com.br/private-media/docs/namefile.pdf

If anyone finds errors, tips for improving the settings, please indicate! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just removed from `nginx.conf` location that refers to private media like so:

```
upstream "my domain" {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://"my domain";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

    #location /privatefiles/ {
    #    alias /home/app/web/privatefiles/;
    #}

    # Error & Access logs
    error_log /home/app/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /home/app/logs/access.log;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

}
```

Don't forget to set `DEBUG = False`, then it should worked perfectly. Every time I tried to access to private media without login in, it redirected me to login page.

This is my `settings.py`

```
...
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

MEDIA_URL = "/mediafiles/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mediafiles")

PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "privatefiles")

PRIVATE_STORAGE_AUTH_FUNCTION = 'private_storage.permissions.allow_authenticated'
...
```

and my main `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

import private_storage.urls <--- this is for private storage

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('rubric/', include('rubric.urls')),
    path('warehouse/', include('warehouse.urls')),
    path('preoffers/', include('preoffers.urls')),
    path('offers/', include('offers.urls')),
    url('^privatefiles/', include(private_storage.urls)) <--- this is for private storage
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

'internal' param tells nginx it's not accessible from the outside.

We access application and then redirect to nginx

settings.py

```
PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'private-media')
PRIVATE_STORAGE_AUTH_FUNCTION = 'private_storage.permissions.allow_staff'
PRIVATE_STORAGE_SERVER = 'nginx'
PRIVATE_STORAGE_INTERNAL_URL = '/private-x-accel-redirect/'
```

nginx

```
location /private-x-accel-redirect/ {
    internal;
    alias /var/www/private-media/;
}
```